# Spring Boot Static Folder In Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docker, spring-boot

In Spring Boot project I have to change the default location to the resource folder. I use this code to achieve the wanted results:

```
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            String location = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/pictures/";

            registry.addResourceHandler("/pictures/**").
                    addResourceLocations(location);

            super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        }
    };
}
```

On my local machine everthing works. When create the docker image and run it everyhing seems to be ok but when I try to request some of the files in the directory it throws this exception:

```
2017-08-23 13:03:48.652 ERROR 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.net.UnknownHostException: pictures
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:964) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:924) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1019) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1005) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
... more logs (not sure if they are needed to find the problem)
```

The whole [stack](https://pastebin.com/fcMxW8En) of the exception.

I checked if the the pictures folder is in the docker images and yes its there. I am not sure what causes this problem. Can it be that `file:` before the file path? I use this variable `System.getProperty("user.dir")` in another function and it works properly so it mustn't be the problem.

Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
RUN mkdir /files
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xss512k"
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

Comment: The strange part is that it raises an `UnknownHostException` from the `FTPClient` , like if it was trying to do a FTP connection to a host called `pictures` .

Comment: Yes, that's why I can't find anything on the internet and think that it's caused by Docker.

Comment: Do you have a part of your code that attempts to do FTP connections and could you post it (also see if the stack trace indicates one of your custom classes).?

Comment: what is the value of user.dir in docker ?

Comment: @Berger I don't to do any FTP connections and none of my classes appear in the exception.

Comment: @Elyran I tried to open the file that I am trying to access with code and I succeeded. `File test = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/pictures/products/test.txt");`

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to see the whole stack trace to see what is calling the ftp connect

Comment: @Elyran https://pastebin.com/fcMxW8En

Comment: Which docker image are you using? Paste your dockerfile please

Comment: what if you leave out the _"file:"_ part and just use `String location = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/pictures/";`

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Tried and it doesn't work - like that even on my pc doesn't work.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Updated the post.

Comment: I don't see you copying an pictures folder? and also where inside the docker container is folder located?

Comment: @TarunLalwani It's because I mount this folder from a volume. It's located in the root directory `/`. Here are some lines that I added to test if the problem is not caused by the mounted volume: `RUN mkdir /pictures
RUN mkdir /pictures/products
RUN touch /pictures/products/test.txt`

Comment: Try changing `"file:"` to `"file://"` and see if that helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks!!

Comment: @kirpt, worked? If yes then I will add answer and explanation

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, it worked! The explanation will be very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two formats that can be used when you do local file handling of resources

`file:abc/xyz` and `file:///abc/xyz`.

`file:abc/xyz` means you want to serve from a relative path `abc/xyz`.

`file:///abc/xyz` means you want to serve from an absolute path `/abc/xyz`.

In your case `user.dir` was probably `/` inside the docker container making the path as `file://pictures`. Because of which the FTP handler was being activated by Java